# Python 2.x get unix signal name for signalnum (code)?

Tags: python, unix, signals, idioms

Is there a more pythonic way to get the signal name from a signal code? My current approach:

```
import signal
dict((getattr(signal,na),na) for na in dir(signal) if na[:3]=='SIG')
```

I looked the 2.7 [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) docs without success for such a map. If it has one it eluded me. Is there a better approach?

Comment: I don't think that Python provides such an int -> name mapping. Personally I wouldn't use a list comprehension here because I find the code too hard to read. `n[:3]` could be written as `n.startswith('SIG')` and generally using `n` in the second part seems misleading because it's not a number but a symbol name.

Comment: @FelixSchwarz hm, I used `n` as in *n*ame. edit to `na`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension, which I think looks a little nicer:

```
{getattr(signal, n) : n for n in dir(signal) if n.startswith('SIG')}
```

Also, your original comprehension is over-complicated. You've added an extra `for n in` when you don't need one. You could just write it like this:

```
dict((getattr(signal,n),n) for n in dir(signal) if n[:3] == 'SIG')
```

Comment: overcomplicated: you're right, I did the edit! dict-comprehension: sure is nicer. which is the lowest version of python that supports it? (I need to support some old versions unfortunately).

Comment: @naxa Dict comprehensions are 2.7+. If you need to support earlier you'll have to go with the `dict(...) ` approach.

Comment: Note that the above may incorrectly report e.g. `SIG_SETMASK` instead of `SIGINT`.  Change to e.g. `{getattr(signal, n): n for n in dir(signal) if n.startswith('SIG') and not n.startswith('SIG_')}`.